# Updating ESP32 Firmware via Ethernet(Internet)

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp8266, ethernet, esp32

I am having an ESP32 development board which communicates through Ethernet via TCP/IP protocol.I want to update the firmware through Ethernet (ESP32 dev board is connected to Enc28J60 Ethernet Lan Network Module connected via SPI protocol).I have seen lots of other OTA updations but through same network.Can any one help me to figure this out so that i can upgrade the firmware through the internet?

Answer (score 1):

My [general ArduinoOTA library](https://github.com/jandrassy/ArduinoOTA) supports ESP32 too.

The ArduinoOTA library bundled with ESP8266 and ESP32 Arduino packages works only with native WiFi libraries. My general ArduinoOTA library allows to upload a sketch to esp8266 or esp32 over Ethernet with Ethernet or UIPEthernet library. Upload over the native WiFi library works too.

**If you want to download the update bin, see [the OTASketchDownload example](https://github.com/jandrassy/ArduinoOTA/blob/master/examples/Advanced/OTASketchDownload/OTASketchDownload.ino).**

To use this library instead of the bundled library, the bundled library must be removed from the boards package library folder. To override the configuration of OTA upload in platform.txt, copy the platform.local.txt file from extras folder of this library next to platform.txt file in boards package installation folder.